# Compare file1 with one column to two columns from file2

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, cut

I have two files: file1.txt and file2.txt

```
#file1.txt
xap1
NM_121
abc4
xxx0
uvw


#file2.txt
A123  001  xap1    mmmmm
B123       xxx0    nnnnn
C123  003  yyy1    ppppp
D123  004  zzz1    NM_121
E123  005  abc4    llllll
F123       jjjj    www
```

I want following output based on matching of column 1 of file1 with column 3 and column 4 of file2, get column 2 from file2 and print both:

```
#file3.txt
xap1    001
NM_121  004
abc4    005
xxx0    NA
uvw     NA
```

I used the following command, but don't know how to print column 1 from file1:

```
grep -w -F -f file1.txt file2.txt | awk '{print $2) > file3.txt
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the input a tab separated file?

Comment: Yes, I can only get column2 from file2 based on column1 from file1. But I want to keep column1 from file1 too.

Comment: So when a the field is missing from column2 in file2.txt, then there are just two tabs?

Comment: Include in your sample input/output the case where the value in `file1` doesn't exist at all in `file2`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton Done.

Comment: No, all strings in file1 still exist in file2.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton Done.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR {
    map[$3] = map[$4] = ($2 == "" ? "NA1" : $2)
    next
}
{ print $1, ($1 in map ? map[$1] : "NA2") }

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
xap1    001
NM_121  004
abc4    005
xxx0    NA1
```

I used 2 different NA values to distinguish between cases where $1 exists in file 2 but has a blank entry (e.g. `xxx0`) vs where it just doesn't exist in file2, e.g. some random string like `foobar`:

```
$ cat file1
xap1
NM_121
abc4
xxx0
foobar

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
xap1    001
NM_121  004
abc4    005
xxx0    NA1
foobar  NA2
```

Massage to suit.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton Thanks, but would it be possible to use a combination of grep and awk or only grep.

Answer (score -1):

The following:

```
{
join -t$'\t' -12 -23 -o1.1,1.2,2.2 <(nl -w1 file1.txt | sort -t$'\t' -k2) <(sort -t$'\t' -k3 file2.txt)
join -t$'\t' -12 -24 -o1.1,1.2,2.2 <(nl -w1 file1.txt | sort -t$'\t' -k2) <(sort -t$'\t' -k4 file2.txt)
} |
sort -t$'\t' -k1 | cut -f2- |
# insert NA is it's missing value
sed 's/\t$/\tNA/'
```

With the following recreation of input files:

```
cat <<EOF >file1.txt
xap1
NM_121
abc4
xxx0
EOF

# used tr to recreate a tab separated file
tr ' ' '\t' <<EOF >file2.txt
A123 001 xap1 mmmmm
B123  xxx0 nnnnn
C123 003 yyy1 ppppp
D123 004 zzz1 NM_121
E123 005 abc4 llllll
EOF
```

Outputs:

```
xap1    001
NM_121  004
abc4    005
xxx0    NA
```

Tested on [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/FullOrganicTelephones).

Short explanation of main points:

- `nl -w1 file1.txt | sort -t$'\t' -k2` - number lines in file2.txt and sort with the second field
- `join` - join files. We join file1.txt with file2.txt twice - first on first field and 3rd field and then on first field and 4th field from file1.txt and file2.txt. For `join` inputs have to be sorted on the joined fields.
- `sort -t$'\t' -k1 | cut -f2-` - the lines in `file1.txt` are numbered, so later we can sort them using the line numbers (ie. restore original sorting order of file1.txt) and remove the line numbers
- `sed 's/\t$/\tNA/'` - the field is empty in `file2.txt`, while OP specified the output to be "NA". If the second column is missing from the output, insert the chracters `NA` there.
- `>( ... )` is a [process substition](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)
- If a value is matched with both 3rd and 4rd field, it will be twice in the output. It could be just piped via `sort -k1 -u` to remove the duplicates, depending on needs.

The sorting and numbering of `file1.txt` could be optimized with some `tee` like `nl | sort | tee >(join - file2.txt) >(join - file2.txt)`

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk Thanks, but it is very complicated. I am looking for something with a combination of grep and awk or only grep.